# Can't get print_control_identifiers() to work in a very basic scenario

Tags: python, pywinauto

`Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'print_control_identifiers' were found (typo?)` error is returned for Application and DialogWrapper classes. WindowSpecification class returns None.

I was expecting the `WindowSpecification` to return at least *something*. Because a few milliseconds later I am able to interact with it. For example I successfully iterate like this: `for child in self.main_window_specification.Children():`

Code:

```
def run(self, output_mod_name):
        """ Runs the ArtManager executable """
        logger.info("Starting art manager")
        self.app = Application(backend="win32").start(self.path)
        logger.debug(f"Type of self.app: {type(self.app)}")
        try:
            logger.debug("This is expected to fail")
            logger.debug(f"{self.app.print_control_identifiers()}")
        except Exception as exc:
            traceback_formatted = traceback.format_exc()
            logger.debug(traceback_formatted)
        logger.debug("Launched art manager process")
        # wait for the window to come up
        expected_window_title = f"S: {output_mod_name} | A: {output_mod_name} | Art Manager"

        self.main_window_dialog = self.app.window(best_match=expected_window_title).wait('ready', timeout=10)
        logger.debug(f"Type of self.main_window_dialog: {type(self.main_window_dialog)}")
        try:
            logger.debug("This is expected to fail too")
            logger.debug(f"{self.main_window_dialog.print_control_identifiers()}")
        except Exception as exc:
            traceback_formatted = traceback.format_exc()
            logger.debug(traceback_formatted)

        logger.info("Art manager started")
        self.main_window_specification = self.app.window(best_match=expected_window_title)
        logger.debug(f"Type of self.main_window_specification: {type(self.main_window_specification)}")
        try:
            logger.debug("This is expected to work")
            logger.debug(f"{self.main_window_specification.print_control_identifiers()}")
        except Exception as exc:
            traceback_formatted = traceback.format_exc()
            logger.debug(traceback_formatted)
        logger.debug("Aquired handle on Art Manager window")
```

Output:

```
2023-10-09 12:21:24,756 - (art_manager.py:76) - tqma - INFO - Starting art manager
2023-10-09 12:21:26,007 - (art_manager.py:78) - tqma - DEBUG - Type of self.app: <class 'pywinauto.application.Application'>
2023-10-09 12:21:26,008 - (art_manager.py:80) - tqma - DEBUG - This is expected to fail
2023-10-09 12:21:26,008 - (art_manager.py:84) - tqma - DEBUG - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\binary_automation\art_manager.py", line 81, in run
    logger.debug(f"{self.app.print_control_identifiers()}")
  File "pywinauto\application.py", line 180, in __call__
AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'print_control_identifiers' were found (typo?)

2023-10-09 12:21:26,008 - (art_manager.py:85) - tqma - DEBUG - Launched art manager process
2023-10-09 12:21:26,021 - (art_manager.py:90) - tqma - DEBUG - Type of self.main_window_dialog: <class 'pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.DialogWrapper'>
2023-10-09 12:21:26,021 - (art_manager.py:92) - tqma - DEBUG - This is expected to fail too
2023-10-09 12:21:26,021 - (art_manager.py:96) - tqma - DEBUG - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\binary_automation\art_manager.py", line 93, in run
    logger.debug(f"{self.main_window_dialog.print_control_identifiers()}")
AttributeError: 'DialogWrapper' object has no attribute 'print_control_identifiers'

2023-10-09 12:21:26,021 - (art_manager.py:98) - tqma - INFO - Art manager started
2023-10-09 12:21:26,022 - (art_manager.py:100) - tqma - DEBUG - Type of self.main_window_specification: <class 'pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification'>
2023-10-09 12:21:26,022 - (art_manager.py:102) - tqma - DEBUG - This is expected to work
2023-10-09 12:21:26,101 - (art_manager.py:103) - tqma - DEBUG - None
2023-10-09 12:21:26,101 - (art_manager.py:107) - tqma - DEBUG - Aquired handle on Art Manager window
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `app` object doesn't have method `dump_tree()` or its alias `print_control_identifiers()`. It is a method of WindowSpecification object only. In future releases it will be added to a wrapper object as well. No plans for `Application` object though.

But for `Application` and `Desktop` objects there is method `windows()` to return a list of top level windows as wrappers. Their properties/methods can be used to create proper `WindowSpecification`.

EDIT:
By default method `dump_tree()` prints to stdout / console. It can be redirected to a file by the method parameter `filename`. Yes, the method returns `None`. This is by design from the very beginning.

Comment: I don't get such method for WindowSpecification either - that is the strange thing.
self.main_window_specification.dump_tree() (says no such attribute/member)

Comment: Maybe because window title is not similar to `"main_window_specification"`. It is a typo resistant search. It is equivalent to `self.window(best_match="main_window_specification").dump_tree()`

Comment: I don't think that's the case. The code assigning that is `self.main_window_specification = self.app.window(best_match='ArtManager')`. It works correctly as can then further work with return instance of `WindowSpecification`. It's just that it doesn't have `dump_tree()` method somehow

Comment: This is indeed the case: `self.app.print_control_identifiers()`, because `Application` object doesn't have this method! This is the method of WindowSpecification. Your second line of the code in the question looks like a correct WindowSpecification which has such method.  By the way, the log is not provided. And how `self.app` object was created? Please edit your question with clear steps to reproduce and the full traceback.

Comment: I added more debug and more code. Just edited whatever was there and added better version. It looks like print_control_identifiers() indeed works  for WindowSpecification but returns None

Comment: By default method `dump_tree()` prints to stdout / console. It can be redirected to a file by the method parameter `filename`. Yes, the method returns `None`. This is by design from the very beginning. Also it's questionable if you really need `backend="win32"`, it depends on the application type.

Comment: I'm developing in Docker. The image that I am using does not have UIA so using win32 is not a choice. Thank you for the explnation. Outputting into console is a rather unexpected way of doing it. Python conventin for any method is to return something. User can print the returned value wherever they want later. Printing straight to stdout is weird - this is not something you see often. Are you willing to post this as an answer  so that I can accept?

Comment: Well, I got your concern about return value. I need to think how to handle it with some deprecations in the future. Also I've added this recent explanation to the answer. Hope it's complete now.

Comment: Thank you for everything. You're doing a great work maintaining the library. And I find it very convenient and easy to use. Please keep doing what you're doing!